# Uploadify - submitting form after upload

Tags: php, javascript, uploadify

I am using Uploadify and am having problems submitting a form to uploaded1.php after upload, it literally doesn't submit to there, here is the code;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="uploadify/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'uploaded1.php',
    'cancelImg' : 'uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : '/uploads',
    'onAllComplete' : function(event,data) {
      document.getElementByID('someForm').submit();
    }

  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="someForm" action="someFile.php" method="post">
<input name="someField" type="text" />
<input id="someID" name="someName" type="file" />
<input onclick="$('#someID').uploadifyUpload()" type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

How can i can that code to submit the form after? People might only know if they have worked with Uploadify before.

Comment: What's `#file_upload`? I can't see element with this ID in your code.

Comment: It's an element in one of the other included files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in your `<form>` tag for upload to work.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ....>
```

Comment: Added that, but after the upload, its not submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

change `<form id="someForm" action="someFile.php" method="post">` to `<form id="someForm" action="someFile.php" name="someForm" method="post">`
And change

```
document.getElementByID('someForm').submit();
```

TO

```
document.someForm.submit();
```

I just added a name attribute to the form tag and submitted it using the name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
'onAllComplete' : function(event,data) {
    $('#form').submit();
},
```